# Replace unknown alphanumeric character in string in Python

Tags: python, regex, string, python-2.7

I have the below aspect of a string:-

> "a*.b*"

The '*' represents an unknown alphanumeric character as this data is being scraped and so the aspect of the string could be "a1.b1" or "az.bz" for example. Likewise, this appears in a longer piece of string and so could appear in :

```
"http://www.a*.b*.com" where '*' = '1'.
```

The lengths of the strings are unknown.

What I want to do is that for each time the pattern 'a*.b*' is encountered within the string (where '*' is an alphanumeric character, I wish for the letter 'a' to be replaced with 'z' so:-

> 'a1.b1' becomes 'z1.b1' and 'a4.b1' becomes 'z4.b1'

As said, the above features WITHIN a string.

Any advice?

Comment: Have you researched Python regex and come up with an attempted solution yet?

Comment: I'll take a look thanks Elzion. I've been using the replace function but can only get that to run on a defined partial string with known characters as opposed to unknown characters following a pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
lst = ["http://www.a3.bs.com",
       "http://www.a1.bw.com",
       "http://www.a2.be.com",
       "http://www.a3.br.com"]

for i in re.findall("http://www\.a[0-9a-zA-Z]\.b[0-9a-zA-Z]\.com", " ".join(lst)):
    print re.subn('a', 'z', i)[0]
```